# Can a static constructor reduce the performance of accessing static methods?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, static, static-constructor

A static constructor is executed the first time you access a static member.  Knowing this, I have several questions:

- Does this mean that every time I access a static method, the runtime must check if the static constructor has been called?
- Does this incur a performance hit?
- Do "constructor-less" static classes avoid this performance hit?

**[EDIT]**: I would like to clarify that I'm NOT concerned with micro-optimization.
I am asking this question because it is a **design** decision.  If a static constructor incurs a performance hit, then I will design my code with that in mind, and will be more aware of the decisions that may affect performance.

Here's an example to illustrate my question.  Would there be any benefit of taking the `Independent` method and putting it in a separate static class?  That way, it would not have to check if static `Test` had been initialized.  [**Update** See my answer below for a better, simpler example].

```
static class Test {
  // Static constructor with dependent method:
  static int x;
  static Test() { x = 5; }
  static int Dependent() { return x; }

  // Static, independent method:
  static int Independent(int y) { return y+1; }
}
```

[Here's the quote](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BeforeFieldInit.aspx) from the C# specification about the static constructor:

> The execution of a static constructor is triggered by the first of the
>   following events to occur within an application domain:
>
> - An instance of the class is created.
> - Any of the static members of the class are referenced.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921828/static-constructors-cause-a-performance-over-head

Comment: I read that post, but it definitely differs from my question.  It compares the performance of **type-initialization** vs **static constructor**.  I'm interested in knowing if accessing a method is slowed down by a static constructor.  I re-read the "duplicate", including all answers AND links, and still don't have an answer to my question!

Comment: I think it's on field access and not on method call. But yes, there can be a noticeable performance reduction in some scenarios.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I usually criticize premature optimization.  However, I'm more interested in developing good design patterns, and if having a static constructor is known to incur a performance hit, then it's not a very good practice to design static methods that might incur that hit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to the lack of answers, and under @Jobo's direction, I decided to test this for myself.

Here are my test classes:

```
static class WithConstructor {
    static WithConstructor(){ }
    public static int Square(int x){ return x*x; }
}
static class NoConstructor {
    public static int Square(int x){ return x*x; }
}
```

Compiled for Release, using .NET 4.0, the results were very consistent:

```
╔═════════════╦══════════════════╦═════════╦═══════════════╗
║ Iterations: ║ With Constructor ║ 4513 ms ║ Improvement:  ║
║ 1000000000  ║ No Constructor   ║ 3072 ms ║ 33%           ║
╚═════════════╩══════════════════╩═════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Therefore, I'm going to answer my own questions:

- If a static constructor exists, then a static method will incur a (microscopic) performance hit, because the `beforefieldinit` flag must always be checked.
- If a static constructor does not exist, then the method will not incur the performance hit.

Answer (score 2):

Why not test it yourself?

Call your Independent method a number of times like specified above.
Then make an own static class with the same method and call it the same number of times.

Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx for measuring.

My guess would be it won´t matter...

You could also write something to Console in your static Constructor to check if had been called.
Finding out for yourself will last longer than some theroetical answer, just my 2 cents.

Comment: I think I will.  I'm really surprised there isn't a well known answer.

Comment: @Scott there isn't a well known answer because this is most likely not a bottleneck for anyone. There is even a chance of it removing that constructor and instead defaulting the value of X to 5.

Comment: @Rangoric I failed to mention this in my OP (it's in there now), but I'm not as interested in the performance as I am in the design decisions.  When designing a static method, it definitely helps to understand possible performance hits, and in this case, having a good design pattern will help avoid these hits.

Answer (score 0):

static constructor can reduce performance of the first method caller. Indead, first caller is changed to test if static constructor is already called but other caller if not affected.