# Really weird behavior involving a static constructor in a generic class

Tags: c#, class, generics, constructor, static

I stumbled on this really weird behavior while doing some micro benchmarks of various common operations like boxing, casting, object allocation, etc, in order to better learn how to implement a data structure library I've been working on.

Basically, having a static constructor (even if it is empty) in a generic class causes any method call to be drastically slower, but only if the type parameter is of a specific kind (probably a reference type). This also applies to any lambdas defined in the body. Lambdas do eventually get translated to methods in nested classes, so I guess nested classes are affected as well (?). Strangely, having a complicated *initializer* has no impact.

The performance impact is much higher than a normal *interface* method call, and is around as large as a virtual generic method call (this from other research).

What is the reason for this? This is the first time I've been genuinely stumped by how .NET behaves. I was under the impression that a static constructor runs once, and has little effect otherwise.

The code appears below. You can fiddle with a longer version here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/e15ndG

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Linq;
namespace Tests {
    //this is used for benchmarks
    internal class Bench {
        public int Drops = 5;
        public int Runs = 10;
        public int MsTimeout = 20000;
        public Stopwatch Watch = new Stopwatch();

        public double InvokeTest(Action act) {
            Action runner = () => {
                for (int i = 0; i < Drops; i++) {
                    act();
                }
                Watch.Reset();
                Watch.Start();
                for (int i = 0; i < Runs; i++) {
                    act();
                }
                Watch.Stop();
            };
            var thread = new Thread(() => runner());
            thread.Start();
            var success = thread.Join(MsTimeout);
            return success ? Watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds/Runs : -1;
        }
    }       
    internal static class GenericObjectStaticConstructor<T>{
        static GenericObjectStaticConstructor() {} 
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        public static void NothingAtAll() {}

        public static void SeemsVerySimple(int iterations) {
            var z = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                NothingAtAll();
            }
        }
    }
    public static class GenericObjectNoStaticConstructor<T>{
        private static int DoNothing(int x) { 
            return x;   
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        private static void DoNothingAtAll() {}

        public static void SeemsVerySimple(int iterations) {
            for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                DoNothingAtAll();
            }
        }       
    }       
    public class Program {
        public static void Main (String[] args) {
            var bench = new Bench();
            var time1 = bench.InvokeTest(() => GenericObjectStaticConstructor<string>.SeemsVerySimple(1000000));
            var time2 = bench.InvokeTest(() => GenericObjectStaticConstructor<int>.SeemsVerySimple(1000000));
            var time3 = bench.InvokeTest(() => GenericObjectNoStaticConstructor<string>.SeemsVerySimple(1000000));
            var time4 = bench.InvokeTest(() => GenericObjectNoStaticConstructor<int>.SeemsVerySimple(1000000));
            Console.WriteLine("Static Constructor<String>: {0}, Static Constructor<int>: {1}, NoConstructor<string>: {2}, NoConstructor<int>: {3}", time1, time2, time3, time4);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't distil the code down to something that demonstrates the issue and which can be posted in the question?

Comment: It is probably connected to how generics are instantiated: the CLR creates a specific "version" of a generic class for each value type it is used for. So for *MyClass<int>*, after the first time the static constructor is run, it is easy for the CLR to not call it again (the CLR can change the method table of the class so that the initializer is skipped, for example). **BUT** the CLR creates a single shared "version" of generic class for all the referene types **together**. This means that it can't do an optimization like that, because otherwise the other shared versions of the generic class

Comment: wouldn't have the static constructor run. I won't post a full response, but I think this should be a starting point

Comment: @xanatos Ahhh together with the answer Can Baycay linked to, that makes a lot of sense! The CLR probably has to jump through additional hoops to make sure whether it called the static constructor or not. It's a bit weird it doesn't need to jump through similar hoops to make sure initialization has been performed, though. If anyone compiles this information into an answer, I'll be sure to accept it.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Although I feel the full version is more intriguing, I shortened it and put the code as part of the question.

Comment: You appear to be running into a jitter limitation.  The call to NothingAtAll() does not get inlined.  And much worse, the PrecodeFixupThunk call into the jitter does not get eliminated either.  First time I've seen this happen.  Pretty hard to come up with a decent reason for that, I don't see any good leads in the jitter source for this either.  The non-generic version is very fast.  If you get a repro for this in VS2015 then you can post to connect.microsoft.com about this.

Answer (score 1):

.NET works hard and does so many things behind the doors to deliver smooth experience to programmers.

Here is a good explanation of the performance hit:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/2922740/2129382

Comment: Together with xanatos's comment, this makes a lot more sense. If you were to clarify things further, I'll be sure to accept the answer.

Comment: That's okay, I'm just here to help :) But I have a limited time so my answers are short :) About your question, C# is an evolving language. You can see type initialization behavior changed over time (http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0/). And probably will change further in future. So in your case, to select between static constructors or other methods, I would not try to deeply understand (though it would be fun) what's going on inside CLR. I mean I would not write code depending on current state. Because they are constantly changing things :)

Comment: Instead I would try to see if users of my code will ever need this performance boost. If they need, then I would not use static constructors. Otherwise, it's really time saving to use what .NET provides us :)

Comment: the problem is that I'm writing a data structure library that's supposed to be better than the competition. My users will be exactly those people who need the extra performance and functionality my library provides. In order to achieve high performance, I have to be aware of implementation details, and adjust my implementation if they change. You really are right in 99.9999% of the time, though. Things like static constructors and method calls don't matter a tiny bit.